# Can a booking agency (rightfully) deduct a fee for refunding cancelled flights?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, cancellations, fees-and-charges, refunds

A person had their flights cancelled and was told by the airline to seek a refund from the booking agency (RCG).

RCG said they'll charge an admin fee of SEK 399 (whereas the booking cost SEK 640)

Is this even legal (in the EU), given the flights were cancelled?

Comment: According to their terms & conditions,  RCG charges SEK 595 for this service. Impudent, but likely legit. Why did a person book through an agency with such conditions?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo If you cancel yourself, sure, but surely not when **the flights are cancelled**!!?? And well, the round trip cost SEK 640, far less than elsewhere.

Comment: SEK 399 is like USD 40. As fees go, high but not insane.  **The outlier here is the cost of the flight SEK 640 = USD 63 = EU 58**.

Answer (score 3):

The airline agreed to provide you with a service, transporting you from A to B for some fee (presumably SEK 241 640-399). They didn't deliver so you deserve a refund of SEK 241.

The booking agency provided a service, which was to book a flight for you, for SEK 399. They did that. That the airline couldn't provide the flight they booked is not their fault.

There might be some redress if the fee was clearly unreasonable (i.e. the flight cost was disguised as a booking fee) but at SEK 399 that isn't really the case.